# when column matches text, copy the whole line to new file

Tags: perl

I'm writing a Perl script. If the text in a specified column (here column 13) matches a certain text namely 'one' or 'two', then the whole line (so all columns) should be copied to another file. My input is a tab-delimited .txt file.

This is what I have so far:

```
my $table1 = $ARGV[0];
open(my $variants,$table1) || die "$! $table1";
open(my $out,'>',"filtered.txt") || die "Can't write new file: $!";

while(<$variants>){
    chomp;
    my @line=split(/\t/);  #split on tabs
    if (($line[12] =~ m/one/) || ($line[12] =~ m/two/)){
        print $out "$_";
    }   
}
```

Since I'm getting a 'use of uninitialized value' error, I wanted to know what needs to be changed in this code.

Comment: What's your question? There's not a single question mark in your post. What are you having problems with? What do you want us to do?

Comment: `$line[12]` is the 13th column. You're also missing a `"` in this line: `print $out $_ \n";`

Comment: My piece of code was actually working. The uninitialized value error was due to a problem with the input file.

Comment: `perl -lane 'print if($F[12]=~/\bone\b|\btwo\b/) your_file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great example of a program that should be written using the Unix filter model.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  my @line = split /\t/;

  # Do you mean 12? That's the 13th field
  print if $line[12] =~ /one/ || $line[12] =~ /two/;
}
```

Simpler to write and easier to understand. Oh, and far more flexible (no hardcoded filenames).

Call it like this:

```
$ ./my_filter < input_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

What is the problem?

```
perl -F'\t' -ane'print if $F[11]=~/one|two/' input > output
```

Comment: This requires anchoring the regex, unless you specifically require substring matching, such that "toner" matches the regex "one".

Comment: @tripleee I don't see this requirement neither in question neither in provided code. One can easily change regexp accordingly to `/^(?:one|two)$/` or `/\b(?:one|two)\b/` but mine code will work exactly same as provided code example except more efficiently.

Comment: Agree that the question isn't entirely clear on this point. Your interpretation is reasonable, but I'm guessing not what the OP intends.